# How do you maintain/configure fonts or icons properly in Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, wayland, icons, fontconfig

What I've understood with fonts and icons is that when the fonts are installed, and when the fonts used are explicitly specified by the application, the fonts will be correct.

However, with most of the applications and stuffs, the fonts don't work as intended. Like when I copy from a Iosevka Font from Font Manager and paste it into another app, it will output differently. Now, I'm having trouble with Clapper in Wayland, where the icons were correct the first time I opened it, but now it's just the "Warning Information" icon all over the app. How do I fix it right now and when such problems arise in the future?
[image: Here is the picture]

Comment: Where are you installing these fonts/icons?

Comment: @ajgringo619 From Arch or AUR or sometimes manually to /usr/share/fonts when I need it, the wrong fonts even happened to my PC yesterday when I got back home, the fonts were wrong, it was all correct the other day

Comment: Hmmm...maybe running `sudo fc-cache -rv`, then rebooting will help.

Comment: @ajgringo619 it does help, but only partially, the volume icon is back, but the other two is still missing, thank you, it's appreciated but can i completely solve this, because it's pretty annoying, or is it because i'm using hyprland

Comment: `fc-cache` is for fonts; take a look at `gtk-update-icon-cache` for icons.